# Import android mobile wallet to desktop

Tags: wallet, wallet.dat, bitcoin-wallet-app

I have an android wallet (The Andreas Schildbach one). 
Is it possible to import this wallet into my desktop wallet?

I would like to be able to manage my funds using my mobile or my desktop - both looking at the same wallet.

I have been digging through the files in my phone looking for a wallet.dat / .wallet but can't seem to find one.

I did back up my mobile wallet then tried importing the backup file into my desktop wallet, but this did not work.

Comment: related: [Can wallets be shared by different machines?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/4923/5406)

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that you could sync your blockchain wallet with the mobile app. Will set one up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way to export those keys but its possible. Here's a detailed [How-To](http://gary-rowe.com/agilestack/2011/12/28/how-to-recover-lost-bitcoins-from-an-android-wallet/). 
Please note that you need to root your phone to get access to your wallet file.

**Edit:**
I just found another interessting and easier method [here](http://hedinn.is/t3-assets/sw/YourBitcoinWallet/bitcoin-wallet-android-export-private-keys.php), but I didn't tested this one.

**Edit 2:**

> I would like to be able to manage my funds using my mobile or my desktop - both looking at the same wallet.

If you dont mind using a new private key you could import a private key from your bitcoin desktop wallet, sending your bitcoins to this address for further usage.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i will check these methods out later on. The reason why i wanted to use the same private key is because i stupidly bought some GH from a cloud mining company and provided them with my mobile wallet address for some reason. I will try the methods that you have given, but i might be better off just creating a new desktop wallet and changing the address that i supplied to them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it's currently not possible, as Bitcoin Wallet isn't available for any desktop OS and app formats are incompatible to each other.